# Function to return odd numbers within a range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to make script inline value function with CTE
I want a table shows only odd numbers if i input (1) it shows 1,3,5,7,9,11 as I put n < 11
This script shows every numbers 1 to 11.
what should I add on ?

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[oddNumFunction]
 (
 @oddNum int
 )
 Returns TABLE
 AS
 RETURN
 with R_table(n)
 as 
 (
 select @oddNum as n
 union all
 select n + 1 from R_table where  n < 11 

 )
 select * from R_table
```

Comment: `n + 2` instead of `n + 1`

Comment: then if i put @oddnum(2) it will give 2,4,6 .....

Comment: Replace `select @oddNum as n` with `SELECT CASE WHEN @oddNum%2=0 THEN @oddNum+1 ELSE @oddNum END AS n`

Answer (score 5):

Rather than use a recursive CTE, I would go for something simpler:

```
DECLARE @oddNum INT = 1;

SELECT number
 FROM master..spt_values
 WHERE [type] = N'P' 
  AND number % 2 = 1
  AND number BETWEEN @oddNum AND 11;
```

Another way, if you have a numbers table (which is immensely useful). It doesn't have to contain 1,000,000 rows, this is just to demonstrate that it can. With compression, this takes 11 MB; without, 13 MB.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(number INT PRIMARY KEY)
 WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE); -- recommended if your edition supports it

INSERT dbo.Numbers(number) SELECT TOP (1000000) 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id]) 
  FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2;

SELECT number FROM dbo.Numbers; -- prime it
```

(And when you use this, you can create your function `WITH SCHEMABINDING`, which has additional benefits.)

Now:

```
DECLARE @oddNum INT = 1;

SELECT number
  FROM dbo.Numbers
  WHERE number % 2 = 1
  AND number BETWEEN @oddNum AND 11;
```

So your function could be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[oddNumFunction2]
(
  @oddNum INT
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  RETURN
  (
    SELECT number
      FROM dbo.Numbers
      WHERE number % 2 = 1
      AND number BETWEEN @oddNum AND 11
  );
```

---

Performance comparisons, running this 10,000 times (and stuffing the output into a #temp table):

```
Gidil:                 30.31 seconds
Mahmoud:               29.11 seconds
Me (spt_values):       27.91 seconds
Me (numbers):          28.06 seconds
```

The reason is that the small `spt_values` table is already in memory (and we forced the numbers table to be), and the low number of logicals read required is (slightly!) less expensive than the computation of a recursive CTE (even one that only produces at most 6 rows).

I was surprised Mahmoud's came out faster than Gidil's, but I ran this multiple times and the results were consistent. Feel try to test them yourself and compare. While in most cases this performance difference is negligible, I don't hand-wave these things away, and if I've found the most efficient way I know to do something, I would rather use it, even if the runner-up is right on its heels.

---

If you really want this to be a CTE, the following will handle odd numbers given any input (odd or even) between 0 and 11:

```
DECLARE @oddnum INT = 1;

;WITH n(n) AS
( 
  SELECT @oddNum + ((@oddNum-1)%2)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 2 FROM n WHERE n < 11
)
SELECT n FROM n;
```

Comment: @Dongmin Why do you have to use a recursive CTE? Is this a school assignment? Otherwise why have an artificial requirement?

Comment: Coming to SQL Server 2016, Reclusive CTE's... "avoiding the company of other people; solitary"

Comment: Yep XD this is. So i want the clues :3

Comment: So do the course materials not include any information about how to construct a recursive CTE? Does the instructor know you're getting help here?

Comment: in course materials it gives just information of CTE. I need to find out the clues from internet. So i need information :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @oddnum INT = 1; 

WITH R_TABLE(N) 
     AS (SELECT @oddNum AS n 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT N + 2 
         FROM   R_TABLE 
         WHERE  N < 11) 
SELECT * 
FROM   R_TABLE
```

One small suggestion, try out the code before inserting it into a SP or function.
Good luck!

**EDIT**
If you want to make sure it will always return odd numbers even if the parameter ids even, add something like this to your function **before the CTE**:

```
IF @oddnum%2 = 0 

THEN SET @oddnum = @oddnum + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution, fixed for your requirements:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[oddNumFunction]
 (
   @oddNum int
 )
 Returns TABLE
 AS
  RETURN
  with R_table(n)
  as 
  (
   --select @oddNum as n
   SELECT CASE WHEN @oddNum%2=0 THEN @oddNum+1 ELSE @oddNum END AS n
   union all
   select n + 2 from R_table where  n < 11 
  )
  select * from R_table
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db02b/3)**